# Spring-boot(maven) actuator,devtools not working

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm a newbie to spring-boot. Trying to create a simple web application using spring-boot maven. Basic static page display using dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` worked fine. When I included `spring-boot-devtools` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in `pom.xml` it is giving build error `Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging`.

I tried including `spring-webmvc` dependency in pom file, still the result is same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>jspTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jspTest</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin
                            </artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I downloaded this project from `spring.io` (SPRING INITIALIZR  website). Build project is getting failed.

Answer (score 1):

`<scope>runtime</scope>` of `spring-boot-devtools` suppose not to be runtime. In fact according to the doc -

> Developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully
>   packaged application. If your application is launched from java -jar
>   or if it is started from a special classloader, then it is considered
>   a “production application”. Flagging the dependency as optional in
>   Maven or using a custom`developmentOnly` configuration in Gradle (as
>   shown above) is a best practice that prevents devtools from being
>   transitively applied to other modules that use your project.

So, change the dependency as below -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update your pom.xml and change the version number to any previous stable version.It worked for me.

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>**xyz_previous_.RELEASE**</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
```